# How do you know what the units of force are measured in when calculating work with a line integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, gradient-flows

I use an example from Lamar University they have a work function F(x) = kx and determined the spring constant k to be 400 so the work is equal to the integral of 400xdx,   And the answer is 200x^2. Skipping some details clearly the answer will be an AREA as we expected and expressed in Joules.  The units work out very well.  I am a happy camper.

Now let use take the line integral over a region where x = t and y = t^2. And the force is expressed as F= -yi + xj. where i and j are the unit vectors of course.   This will be the integral of F dot product dr.  With respect to t this will clearly be the integral of F doted with drdt/dt and you can choose any value you wish to integrate over.

In what sense is this an area representing work?  That is the essence of my question? How to I unify these two apparently disparate ways of expressing work?  Where are the Joules in the equation F= -yi + xj?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: A joule is a newton-meter. $F$ gives you the force in newtons and $dr$ gives you the distance in meters.